# SQL Server Management Studio: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

Tags: sql

I am using

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.7001.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.17763.1
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.17763.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.17763

When trying to Edit Top 200 Rows of my database I am getting the following error:

### Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

## The technical information is as follows:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

---

Program Location:

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.OpenTableHelperClass.InvokeOpenTableUsingDesigner(Object parentInformation, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.OpenTableHelperClass.EditTopNRows(NodeContext parentContext, Int32 topNValue)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.EditTopNRows.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolsMenuItemBase.MenuInvokedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args)

===================================

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DocumentObjectSite.QueryStatus(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.QueryStatus(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTrackSelectionExPrivate.Register()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConnectSelectionContext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.Activate()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.viewManager_ActiveViewChanged(Object sender, ActiveViewChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ExtensionMethods.RaiseEvent[TEventArgs](EventHandler`1 eventHandler, Object source, TEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Shell.ViewManager.SetActiveView(View view, ActivationType type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ShowInternal(ShowFlags showFlags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.b__26()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(Func`1 method)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.Show()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.MarshalingWindowFrame.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame.Show>b__7a()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.Invoke[TResult](Func`1 method)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.MarshalingWindowFrame.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame.Show()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.InvokeDesigner(IManagedConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.InvokeOpenTable(Object parentInformation, String fileName)

I have tried many of the solutions out there:
I tried installing the most recent service pack SQLServer2012SP4-KB4018073-x64-ENU.exe
I tried running netsh winsock reset as that was suggested.
I tried running the .Net Framework repair Tool

None of these have fixed my problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks